# c# syntax help, about generic programming

Tags: c#

```
 TEntity Single(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
```

Please explain the parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, there is a lot going on here, but lets start with the inside:

`Func<TEntity, bool>` is a delegate that takes an input, which type is generic, so we just call it `TEntity`.  Without any contraints, this can be anything, but a strongly-typed anything.

Out one level is `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>`.  This is the expression tree, which is strongly typed to be a delegate that takes an input and return a bool.  In other words, it is an expression tree (think back to your compilers course) that represents the function.

Finally, the outermost level: `TEntity Single(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)` is a method called `Single` which takes a predicate function in the form of an expression.  What is returned is the same type that is passed into that function.

Essentially, `Single` will take your expression, compile it and execute it against a set of data, returning the first entity in the collection that matches the predicate expression.

Hope this helps?

Comment: Your answer explains it so much better than my, now deleted one, did. I got confused myself trying to read mine! hehe

Comment: A slight clarification is that Single will throw an exception if it finds more than one result unlike First.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) used to specify any delegate function taking any "TEntity" (as defined in this instance by the collection you are calling it on) and returning a bool. In practice, the delegate is specified using a lambda function:

```
items.Single(i => i.Id == 1);
```

In your example, the Single function is an extension method that is applied to a generic collection of TEntity (which I believe don't have any limitations - i.e. must just be objects). Therefore, the type of TEntity is inferred based on the collection that you are calling it on.

Comment: Just picking a minor nit; It's not actually a Lambda expression at all. It is a `Delegate` type which happens to almost always be passed as a Lambda.